# Joomla checkbox communicating with database

Tags: php, database, checkbox, joomla

I have a problem in Joomla, but can't find a solution. I have a test version, which works perfectly, but on the live version it doesn't…

In the admin of Joomla there is a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="jform[certificate]" id="jform_certificate" value="1" class="inputbox">
```

In the database there is table with a column certificate which has either the value '0' or '1'. It get its value from Joomla if the checkbox is checked and saved.

Saving to the database works; I check the checkbox, press 'save' and the value in the database changes from '0' to '1'.

But when I view the checkbox again, it is unchecked though the value in the database is changed, while in /libraries/joomla/form/fields/checkbox.php on line 43 it states `$checked = ((string) $this->element['value'] == $this->value) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';`. This should compare the checkbox value with the database value and if both are equal it should return a checked attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="jform[certificate]" id="jform_certificate" value="1" class="inputbox" checked="checked">
```

For some reason it doesn't get a proper value back from the database? Does anybody know where I should search? Or where I can find the script which adds the checked attribute?

Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION**

I found the problem. The type of the column in the database was a BIT type, I changed it to an INT type and it seems to work now. See answer below.

Comment: Which version of joomla you are using ?

Comment: Joomla! 2.5.17 Stable is the last -not working- version. The test -working- version is Joomla! 2.5.16 Stable. Do you think this is the problem?

Comment: What happens if you dump out $this->value and $this->element['value']? Also you shouldn't need to say jform['certificate'], just 'certificate' should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the column in the database was a BIT type, I changed it to an INT type and it seems to work now.

As I understand this PHP code `$checked = ((string) $this->element['value'] == $this->value) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';` compares an integer, it compares the value number from the checkbox with the value number of the database. The BIT type means that the value '1' in the database means `TRUE` and the value '0' in the database means `FALSE`.